# what is the nuclear cross section dependent on?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, experimental-physics, measurements, fusion

I understand  that the nuclear cross section determines the probability of fusion taking place. When I was talking to my friend he said that the cross section doesn't depend on anything but the particles and their energies. But I fail to understand this. For example, let us consider ionization. I have a hot cathode, and an anode placed at distance from each other. And between them, I have a gas. So the electrons would ionize the gas and move to the anode. But this is rare as most of them miss. So if  I have a magnetic field, the electrons spiral and there is a higher probability of them colliding with neutral atoms (This is used in ion thrusters).

- Now, since the probability increased, shoudn't the cross section increase too?  So the cross section depends on a lot of factors, right? But the confusion arises when almost all websites say that the collision cross section is basically pi(2r)^2 . But isn't it dependent on other aspects? like the magnetic field we just talked about? Then why is it pi(2r)^2?
- Doesn't the same principle apply to fusion? For a certain energy, the gamows factor determines the probability of fusion. Indirectly, the more collisions we have, the higher the fusion cross section. Since, the collisions or collision cross section are higher  the probability of fusion increases.  And because the collision cross section depends on external factors like magnetic fields, nuclear cross section does too, doesn't it?
- The D-T fusion graphs only work for plasmas that are confined and follow a maxwellian distribution don't they? In other words, they only work for  devices that similar to the tokamak.
- So, is the cross section really dependent on various factors like magnetic fields? electric fields? Am i right?

Comment: Look at the definition of crossection http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Nuclear/crosec.html . The flux impinging on the area will affect the probability of hitting the target but not the size of the target. The target has a fixed size in classical physics and in the quantum regime the area can be a function of the impinging particle's energy icle, but the number of impinging particles  do not affect the area .

Comment: What do you mean by flux here? And... the article also talks about an angle, but what is that?

Comment: and are there any other factors affecting the cross section, not just scattering but also could be collision and nuclear? Like magnetic fields? How would that change cross sections?

Comment: flux means number of particles per second ( with a given energy)impinging on the area. In a plasma the flux is a function of  the tail of the energy distribution. It is the enegy that quantum mechanically changes the area, and depending on temperature, the flux distribution in energy changes, so the interaction crossection/area changes but not in a direct way. Direct is the instant of scattering, particle+ target, and the angle is the scattering angle of the products of the scattering.

Comment: A small suggestion, based on your comments above and absolutely. no offence meant. Spend a little while studying classical scattering, in a classical mechanics book, if you are not sure what flux and other terms mean now, then you are making thing more difficult than they need to be in QM and QFT. It's worth the effort, is what I am saying.

Comment: I currently am searching for lectures like the ones on GR and QM from stanford on the internet.  But apparently, I couldn't find any. Hence, I don't know where to learn this from. I don't have any books on this either. Any suggestions?